# jQuery 3.x custom build with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a custom jquery 3.x but I cannot seem to find a way to keep the $.ajax functionalities despite not removing ajax. Here is my build/grunt settings:

```
grunt custom:-css/showHide,-deprecated,-effects,-event/alias,-wrap,-deferred,-exports/amd dist:/build/custom/jquery-custom.js
```

As you can see, I did not include -ajax. I used [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/README.md#how-to-build-your-own-jquery) as reference. Here is the log

```
-css/showHide
-effects
-effects/animatedSelector
-effects/Tween
-deprecated
-event/alias
-wrap
-deferred
-deferred/exceptionHook
-ajax
-ajax/jsonp
-ajax/load
-ajax/parseXML
-ajax/script
-ajax/var/location
-ajax/var/nonce
-ajax/var/rquery
-ajax/xhr
-manipulation/_evalUrl
-event/ajax
-queue
-queue/delay
-core/ready
+core/ready-no-deferred
-exports/amd
```

Ajax is marked as skipped and I still get

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
```

as ajax is skipped despite me not skipping it. How do I include (or not exclude) ajax ? I even tried

```
 +ajax
```

Did not add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found the issue so answering my own question:

I had to remove `-deferred` to get `ajax`